# How to able to type underscore in jtextfield with digits or letters validation

Tags: java, swing

Question:
How do i able to type "_" (underscore) in a jtextfield that already have keyPressed check for digits or letters.

Comment:
Im using Eclipse IDE.

Code:

```
txtin = new JTextField();
        txtin.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                char C = e.getKeyChar();

                if(Character.isLetter(C) ||Character.isDigit(C) ||Character.isISOControl(C) /*|| code to allow "_"*/){
                    txtin.setEditable(true);
                }else{
                    txtin.setEditable(false);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Why are you checking for `Character.isISOControl(C)`?  What's the matter with `C == '_'`?

Comment: Aside: I don't think `setEditable()` is correct here, you want a document filter instead.  But let's fix one problem at a time.

Comment: 1) Don't play with the setEditable(...) method. 2) Don't use a KeyListener. Instead use either a JFormattedTextField or a `DocumentFilter`.

Comment: @markspace, i use that so i can still use the backspace key and delete key.

Comment: @markspace, i quite new to Java... therefore i dont really know how to use a document filter :'3

Comment: `DocumentFilter` is something that you can search the web for. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use:

```
C == '_'
```

If you create a char you need to use `'` not `"`.